# How to calculate (relative) complexity of images programmatically?

Tags: c#, image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick.net

I have searched the internet thoroughly but not much related questions. Even on stackoverflow there is none

So what I want to achieve is rather hard thing to do

I want to calculate complexity of images

Let me show you several examples from the game I develop https://www.monstermmorpg.com/MonsterDex

A very complex and highly detailed Monster artwork I have e.g.

https://www.monstermmorpg.com/Vesuverex-Monster-Dex-18

[image]

And another one which is pretty simplistic

https://www.monstermmorpg.com/Cluckoon-Monster-Dex-152

[image]

So I want to calculate complexity of images.

I want to calculate flat colors complexity, many lines complexity, good light complexity and if there are any other complexities all of them. With having all kind of image complexities I will sort my images and decide which  one fits best to my aim.

So why do I need? When I resize them with ImageMagick, I will apply filters based on image's complexity such as `unsharp` option

It makes huge difference in borders' aliasing

I want to calculate complexity of images in C#

I am willing to use 3rd party libraries, etc.

Comment: "I hope you understand what I mean from complexity". No we don't. Can you mathematically describe what it is? Is "flat colors" complexity? Is it "many lines" complexity? Is it "good light" complexity? Some of these are super easy to compute, some are not

Comment: @AnderBiguri updated my question please check again

Comment: You can use the standard-deviation as a measure.

Comment: @fmw42 I tested standard deviation and it yields poor results

Comment: Compute Canny edges. Then get the local average across the image. Then get the average value of the result

Comment: @fmw42 how to do that can you post as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I do not code in C#. If standard deviation does not work for you, then that likely will not either.

Answer (score 1):

People often use [entropy](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/entropy.html) as a measure of scene complexity. With [libvips](https://www.libvips.org/), take the histogram and compute entropy from that:

```
$ vips hist_find chicken.png x.v
$ vips hist_entropy x.v
5.048871
$ vips hist_find dino.jpg x.v
$ vips hist_entropy x.v
7.574827
```

You can see your dino image is much higher. libvips has [a nice C# binding](https://github.com/kleisauke/net-vips) on nuget --- you'd write something like (untested):

```
using var im = Image.NewFromFile("image.jpg", access: Enums.Access.Sequential);
double entropy = im.HistFind().HistEntropy();
```